# How to add label / text to wxStaticBitmap?

Tags: c++, user-interface, bitmap, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I am trying to add label to wxStaticBitmap, but it is not appearing in the panel. Here is my code.

```
bitmap_file_name = _U("numbertwo.png");
wxBitmap Featurebitmap((bitmap_path + bitmap_file_name), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
wxStaticBitmap *pFeature = new wxStaticBitmap(this, -1, Featurebitmap, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxALIGN_BOTTOM, wxT("Feature Label - text"));
pFeature->SetCursor(wxCursor(wxCURSOR_HAND));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxStaticBitmap` shows only a bitmap, it doesn't support text label. You have many choices to show a label if you need it:

1. Simplest: use a separate `wxStaticText` control.
2. Modify the bitmap itself to draw a label over it.
3. What you probably need as it looks like your control is supposed to be used, and not just be "static": use `wxButton`, which can show both a label and a bitmap.

Comment: I tried to use wxButton, but it is not transparent like in the bitmap. I used the wxTRANSPARENT_WINDOW | wxBORDER_NONE flags but still button is not transparent.

Comment: Yes, buttons are not transparent. They are like all the other buttons on the system you're using right now, which are not transparent neither.

Answer (score 0):

@badaishaibaz

You didn't mention you want the transparent bitmap.

Anyway, what you can do is to create a transparent wxPanel, put both wxBitmap and wxStaticText on it and use that panel.

As Vadim pointed out - you can't do what you want the way you want it.